# Бэкап и восстановление Veeam Backup

Tags: администрирование, восстановление

Сделал бэкап Windows Server 2016, на другом пк пытаюсь развенуть на чистый жесткий диск.
При восстановлении на чистый hdd мне выводит ошибки.

Updating fidl partition structure Error: Failed to write bootstrap code, disk ‘\.\PhydicslDrive0’. Failed to update master boot record  Win 32 error Отказ в доступе.
restore failed: Failed to write bootstrap code disk ‘\.\PhydicslDrive0’. Failed to update master boot record  Win 32 error Отказ в доступе.
Я являюсь админисратором своего пк, что ему еще не хватает?